# change Jenkins shell for only one pipeline

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I make Jenkins use Bash rather than its native shell for just one Jenkins pipeline/Jenkinsfile?  Does the "agent" help me to do this?

I wrote a shell script for deployment but some of the parameters contain whitespace which messes up the resulting command I generate by losing some args. I've found how to avoid this problem by globally configuring Jenkins shell type to be Bash. But when I change the global shell type, my other Jenkins pipelines that use the Jenkins docker plugin syntax get broken when they use the 'sh' command within a docker container. My workaround is to ping pong the global setting for shell type depending on which Jenkins build I want to run. Its a royal PITA.

Comment: Have you considered fixing your script instead?

Comment: Yes! After time struggling with Jenkins, I need to move on. It works in Bash. Let's stick the topic. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm embarrassed to say all I needed was a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

My Jenkinsfile runs a custom (bash) shell script, using Jenkin's [sh command](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/), like in the following:

```
sh "./deploy.sh \"arg1\" \"arg 2\" \"arg3\""
```

In order to force `deploy.sh` to run within Bash, the contents of `deploy.sh` need to include `#!/bin/bash` on the first line, as in:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "deploy args: $@"
```

Regardless, I think there should be a way to tell a Jenkins pipeline that it should run with specific settings, like sh=bash.